# Root file system on /dev/sda4 requires manual fsck

Tags: boot, dual-boot, reboot

I use ubuntu (latest version) and windows 10 dual. But now when I try to open ubuntu, it shows this, please help, I am no computer genius, and I really get lost with such kinds of errors, with not much help available.

```
/dev/sda4: One or more block group descriptor checksums are invalid. FIXED

/dev/sda4: Group descriptor 320 checksums is Ox5dfa, should be Oxc727.

/dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
      
(i.e. without -a or -p options)

fsck exited with status code 4

The root file system on /dev/sda4 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(1n1tramfs)
```

Comment: @Algnis Thanks a lot to you, for saving the day. It magically worked.

Comment: I clicked the checkbox. I cant upvote though, not enough reputation. : )

Comment: FYI:   Your `busybox` shows `1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3  | focal-updates` which isn't the *latest* version; it's the *latest* LTS or four releases ago (2020-April release; latest currently is 2021-October)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fsck /dev/sda4 -y`

This command will definitely work

As it is written there `/dev/sda4` needs a manual `fsck`, this command just give the manual fsck